# Why the binding error occurred in nested TabControl

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am learning WPF TabControl and writing the test code below
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TabControlTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControlTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Name="mainTabControl">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MainTabName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TabControl Name="subTabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding SubTabList}">
                        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubTabName}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding SubTabContent}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    </TabControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<MainTab> mainTabs = new List<MainTab>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AddTestTab("AAA", 2);
        AddTestTab("BBB", 3);

        mainTabControl.ItemsSource = mainTabs;
    }

    private void AddTestTab(string mainTabName, int subTabCount)
    {
        MainTab mainTab = new MainTab(mainTabName);

        for (int i = 0; i < subTabCount; i++)
        {
            SubTab subTab = new SubTab($"{mainTabName}_{mainTab.SubTabList.Count}");
            mainTab.SubTabList.Add(subTab);
        }

        mainTabs.Add(mainTab);
    }
}
```

Test data:

```
internal class MainTab
{
    public string MainTabName { get; set; }

    public List<SubTab> SubTabList { get; set; } = new List<SubTab>();

    public MainTab(string name)
    {
        MainTabName = name;
    }
}

internal class SubTab
{
    public string SubTabName { get; set; }
    public string SubTabContent { get; set; }

    public SubTab(string name)
    {
        SubTabName = name;
        SubTabContent = $"{name} content";
    }
}
```

Screenshots:

[Tab AAA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sboGy.png)

[Tab BBB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOnm.png)

There are two problems

1. Start debugging and click tab[AAA_1] - tab[BBB] - tab[AAA], then the sub TabControl displays incorrectly:

   [selected item missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swysd.png)
2. Start debugging and click tab[BBB],4 binding failures occurred：

   [binding error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5QQs.png)

   > Cannot find source: RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TabControl', AncestorLevel='1'.

In problem 1, it looks like the default selected item is "missing". So I set `[SelectedItem Binding]` for the sub-TabControl, and it works, but I don't know why.

The problem 2, I have no idea at all.

Please help to explain why the problems occur.